# Unable to use basemap of obspy in python. Installation problem

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have a problem on using basemap in python , obspy. I am using these commands:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from obspy import read_inventory, read_events
```

but command window shows me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\basemap.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap
```

Could you help me? I think that something went wrong about the installation but I can not do something...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake finally was in the version of basemap I have previously installed. You have to correct the version in **cp** suffix